# Send $_FILE data to form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an event listener set up in jQuery `$('#file').on("change", function() {});`.

This detects when image has been appended.

Image source is: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...` the plugin does this.

I just want to send that created image to file upload input in my html form. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: I don't know what to do lol, I want to send this appendet image to my form input. My jquerry isn't that good

Comment: I understand it you have the image as base64 string. Send it as regural input field in POST request. File fields are to read files from users filesystem.

Comment: "Send it as regural input field in POST request." I don't understand this completely... can you clarify?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26056642/1208233

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("plugin").change(function(e){
      $("input#image").val(img);
   });
})
</script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="image" id="image" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") === "POST"){
   $image = $_POST["image"];
   // do what you want
}
?>
```

The more information you give, the better we can help you. Also, it's worth trying things yourself as you will learn from mistakes you make.

Comment: `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` reads my consoel log

Comment: You've got 3 options: 1. make a jsfiddle with your code. 2. try to debug it yourself. 3. provide more information about your code and goal

Comment: We were on the right track here but it seems that the newly created base64 string cant be just inserted into form field, I get a security warning. I am using Codeigniter though, maybe this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you send it as an hidden input field? After you post the form, you can do whatever you like with it using php.
Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("plugin").change(function(e){
      $("input#image").val(e.image);
   });
})
</script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="image" id="image" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") === "POST"){
   $image = $_POST["image"];
   // do what you want
}
?>
```

Haven't tested this, but it should be enough to help you get going.
If you want to display the image, just do something like this:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlh9AEZAdUyAK6VZqBmUNjRrNSon+7">
```

Comment: `$("input#image").val(e.image);` will get my appended image data and send it to hidden field?

Comment: It's worth noting that a hidden input field is inherently not secure, and if you are going to use this to get a file to upload, malicious users may be able to splice their own file into header information and force an upload to your server.

Comment: @LazyPeon As you can read in jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val/ it will indeed change the value of your input field.

Comment: but how can I get my appendet image which source looks like: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...`

Comment: What do you mean? `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...` will go to the input field as it's value.

Comment: I get my img like so: `var img = cropper.getAvatar()` which looks like `img = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...` how can I get this data to my form field?